# How to get the right type from type object with generic in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an enum

```
export const trackingKeys = {
  Form: 'form',
  Video: 'video',
} as const
```

I have a type who give for a key a type property

```
export type TrackingPropertiesByKey = {
  [trackingKeys.Form]: { bar : number }
  [trackingKeys.Video]: { foo : boolean }
}
```

And a track function

```
export type TrackingEventKey =
  typeof trackingKeys[keyof typeof trackingKeys]

const track = <T extends TrackingEventKey>(
    event: TrackingEventKey,
    properties?: TrackingPropertiesByKey[T]
  ) => trackFromLib(event, properties)
```

Using `track(trackingKeys.Form, {foo : true, bar: 1 })` doesn't give me na error.

I've got the following type :

```
const track: <TrackingEventKey>(event: TrackingEventKey, properties?: {
    bar: number;
} | {
    foo: boolean;
}) => void
```

I don't want to have `properties?: {bar: number;}|{foo: boolean;}` but in this case `{ bar : number }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also define the relation between the `event` parameter and `T`:

```
const track = <T extends TrackingEventKey>(
    event: T,
    properties?: TrackingPropertiesByKey[T]
) => trackFromLib(event, properties)
```

You specified the type `event` as `TrackingEventKey` but TypeScript needs to know that `event` determines the type of `T` to narrow down the type.

Comment: Thank you @tobias-s !! I found the answer with your help ! 
I will edit my question